# Change text and image on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the image and text colour in a single hover. If I hover the image both the image and text are changed, but if I hover the text only the text will change.

HTML:

```
<td class="iconmenubg "><a href="projectupdate.xhtml" >
    <img src="../images/leftmenu/executionprogress_normal.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/leftmenu/executionprogress_selected.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/leftmenu/executionprogress_normal.png'" />
    Execution Progress</a>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.iconmenubg a {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
    color:#a5aaad !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 34px;
}
.iconmenubg a:hover{
    text-align:center !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important; 
    font-size:12px !important;
}
```

How can I make it so when I hover over the image *or* text, both the image *and* text change?

Comment: Can you post an example of what the resulting HTML looks like. I think the CSS :hover and the JS onmouseover clash with each other, but I'm not sure what happens exactly or what you should do to correct this. Do you have a website you can link to?

Comment: In future HTML/CSS/JS related questions, show the JSF-generated HTML output, not the original JSF source code. HTML/CSS/JS users shouldn't be bothered with server side languages which generate HTML/CSS/JS output. I edited the question to show the minimal HTML output so that those users can at least digest and answer it. Surely JSF users can also answer it, but this is technically not a JSF problem. Once having the answer all you need to do is to write the server side code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output (as you can see by rightclick, *View Source* in a webbrowser)